# Is it possible to determine the constituents of a matrix product, given the result?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a set $M$ of two or more matrices such that every matrix product $X$ composed of matrices drawn with replacement from $M$ is unique.

Is there a set $M$ for which we can determine the constituents (including order) of the matrix product, given the result matrix X?

Edit: I'm specifically interested in the case where the product consists of an arbitrary number of matrices drawn with replacement from $M$, e.g. $M = \{A, B, C\}$ and $X = ABABBBACBAABC$.

Comment: If every matrix in $M$ is invertible, and the products considered are products of just two matrices, the way to determine the constituents, including order, answer is trivial.  Simply left multiply by each of the elements of $M$ and then compare the result to every element of $M$; then if that does not find the product, do the same starting with right multiplying by the inverse of each element of $M$.  The same goes for products of any finite number of matrices.  Did you mean the problem to allow for infinite products? because then it gets a lot tougher.

Comment: Yes, I'm specifically interested in the tougher case; not infinite products necessarily but arbitrary finite products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every matrix product drawn from the set is unique, then take $\{A, B, C, \cdots \}$ to be matrices such that the logs of the determinants $\log |A|, \log |B|, \cdots \}$ are linearly independent over the rationals.  Then given the product $X$, the number of powers of each of the members of $M$ is determined by taking the determinant of $X$ and expressing its log as a sum of the log determinants of the members of $M$.  Since that is a finite number of factors, it only remains to try all the permutations of that finite collection $A^a, B^b, \cdots\}$.

But to get "universal uniqueness"  $M$ must be chosen such that no two of the permutations yield the same product.  Because of the Jacobi identity (the sum of all three cyclic permutations of the three matrix commutator form is zero) it seems likely that that can never be the case for all products of the matrices.

The Jacoby identity is 
$$
[A,[B,C]] + [B,[C,A]] + [C,[A,B]] = 0
$$
where $[X,Y] \equiv XY - YX$.